# Localised Date format without year with Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to achieve showing date in local format but without year. So should be:

- **12 June** for UK
- **June 12** for US

Is it possible to achieve with Joda time?

We've tried "dd MMMM" pattern but it doesn't work.
We've tried `StringFormat.longDate()` and strip year info but are there more elegant solution?

Comment: `String date = LocalDate.now().toString("dd MMMM");`

Comment: @Tiny so it will be different for US and UK?

Comment: I am not aware of whether the API automatically changes its format according to a given locale (It should do intuitively but I choose to remain silent about it as I did not do it myself). If not then, the application using the API will be responsible for providing / supplying an appropriate date format according to a selected locale.

Comment: @Tiny it won't. If you ask joda time to format a date with the pattern dd MMMM, it will use the pattern dd MMMM. Not MMMM dd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath the covers, JodaTime uses the JDK's `java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale aLocale)` - see the sources of `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.StyleFormatter#getPattern(Locale locale)` how it delegates to `java.text.DateFormat`:

```
String getPattern(Locale locale) {
    DateFormat f = null;
    switch (iType) {
        case DATE:
            f = DateFormat.getDateInstance(iDateStyle, locale);
            break;
        case TIME:
            f = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(iTimeStyle, locale);
            break;
        case DATETIME:
            f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(iDateStyle, iTimeStyle, locale);
            break;
    }
    if (f instanceof SimpleDateFormat == false) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No datetime pattern for locale: " + locale);
    }
    return ((SimpleDateFormat) f).toPattern();
}
```

so the per-locale formats are embedded in the JDK, not even in JodaTime.

Using this code, you can get the predefined patterns and outputs for different locales:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime dt = DateTime.now();

    String usFormat = DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("L-", Locale.US);
    String ukFormat = DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle("L-", Locale.UK);

    System.out.println(dt.toString(usFormat));
    System.out.println(dt.toString(ukFormat));
}
```

prints

```
October 20, 2015
20 October 2015
```

However, the patterns are predefined for four styles only: short, medium, long and full, applicable for both date and time parts separately. See the JavaDoc of [`DateTimeFormat#patternForStyle`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#patternForStyle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)):

> The first character is the date style, and the second character is the time style. Specify a character of 'S' for short style, 'M' for medium, 'L' for long, and 'F' for full. A date or time may be ommitted by specifying a style character '-'.

So if you want to drop the year part, you would need to post-process the pattern obtained from `DateTimeFormat.patternForStyle()`. This could be done eg. by dropping all "Y" and "y" characters, but in general, if you want to do it for an arbitrary locale, can produce some messed-up patterns.

Comment: Thank you, Adam! This is a bit better solution since I was removing year from already formatted string, but I could operate with pattern, that fills safer and cleaner