# DateTimeFormat shortDate without year

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I'd like to have a `DateTimeFormat.shortDate()` without the year so that in German it will be displayed like 02.01 and in English it will be displayed like 01/02.

Right now I'm using the following.

```
return DateTimeFormat.shortDate()
    .withLocale(Locale.getDefault())
    .print(dateTime);
```

How can I avoid letting the `DateTimeFormat` print out the year?

Comment: You mean in German 02.01 and in English 01/02

Comment: Yes sorry. Mixed it up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Localised Date format without year with Joda Time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168198/localised-date-format-without-year-with-joda-time)

Comment: Sorry not possible in Joda-Time unless you are willing to do pattern post processing as suggested in linked duplicate (not reliable for all locales!). However, ICU4J and my lib Time4J supports this feature. Example: `ChronoFormatter.ofStyle(DisplayMode.SHORT, Locale.getDefault(), AnnualDate.chronology()).format(AnnualDate.from(MonthDay.of(2, 28)))`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered here:

[Localised Date format without year with Joda Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168198/localised-date-format-without-year-with-joda-time)

At least there is a good example how to deal with your issue.

Another option if you know you will support only some Locales, you could make your own map with needed formats like:

```
Map<Locale, DateTimeFormatter> formats = new HashMap<>();

formats.put(Locale.US, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM"));
formats.put(Locale.GERMAN, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM.dd"));

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = Optional.ofNullable(formats.get(Locale.getDefault()))
    .orElse(DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DEFAULT_PATTERN));

dateTimeFormatter.print(DateTimeUtils.today());
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Once you have 15 reputation you'll be able to flag posts as duplicates. That's the thing to do in this situation. You shouldn't post an answer containing this kind of thing :)